# Check if a PHP SessionID is in use?

Tags: php, session, timeout, sessionid

at one of my project, i store a temporary data in database with a sessionId, and i've to delete them if its sessionId is not in use, is there a simple way to check if session id is in use?

Comment: Why aren't you storing the data in the session (where it will be cleaned up automatically when the session dies)?

Comment: or if you really want to use database - use temporary tables for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if PHP session_id is in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206929/check-if-php-session-id-is-in-use)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 1):

Store a last accessed timestamp, and delete those rows whose time is X minutes earlier than the current time.

Answer (score 1):

You can name your session with session_name ([ string $name ] ),

example: `session_name('myname')`,

and then just check if there is a session id for that name with session_id ([ string $id ] ),

example:

```
if(session_id('myname') != "")
       echo session_id('myname');
         else
      //your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a simple way to check if session id is in use?

If you are using the default session handler then checking if the session file is present and has been modified since time()-session_cache_expire().

However a much better solution would be to use a database-bound session handler. This is much more flexible when trying to look at session data from outside the session, you could just do a simple join to find the matching data, but the right way to solve the problem is to implement the session management code within the session handler (i.e. delete the data when the session is deleted)!