# Clean session based data from DB when session is expired

Tags: php, symfony, session, session-timeout

What is the best way to check in Symfony2 if a session (not the current) by sessionID is expired.

I have a database e.g. id|sessionId|someData and I want to create a command that remove all rows which sessions are expired.

Comment: add status column  to check the status

Comment: the question is how to get the expire status of another session by sessionId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the default symfony session handling which relies on php-sessions you're out of luck.

As soon as your session is expired you get a new one.

**However** if you access to the **session save path** you might try the accepted answer in this question:

[Check if PHP session_id is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206929/check-if-php-session-id-is-in-use)